# How to avoid DISTINCT as a crutch when doing analytic queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, vertica, window-functions

I have a query that I think has a fairly common pattern. Consider this table:

```
id | val | ts
---+-----+-------
 a |  10 | 12:01
 a |  12 | 12:05
 a |   9 | 12:15
 b |  30 | 12:03
```

I want to get the latest value by timestamp for each id. Some ways you can do it:

```
-- where in aggregate subquery
-- we avoid this because it's slow for our purposes
select
  id, val
from t
where (id, ts) in
  (select
    id,
    max(ts)
   from t
   group by id);

-- analytic ranking
select
  id, val
from
  (select
    row_number() over (partition by id order by ts desc) as rank,
    id,
    val
  from t) ranked
where rank = 1;

-- distincting analytic
-- distinct effectively dedupes the rows that end up with same values
select
  distinct id, val
from
  (select
    id,
    first_value(val) over (partition by id order by ts desc) as val
  from t) ranked;
```

The analytic ranking query feels like the one for which it'd be the easiest to come up with an efficient query plan. But aesthetically and maintenance-wise, it's pretty ugly (especially when the table has way more than just 1 value column).
In a few places in production, we use the distincting analytic query when testing shows that performance is equivalent.

Are there any ways to do something like rank = 1 without ending up with such an ugly query?

Comment: Which result do you expect, if there is another row like `a, 10, 13:45`? (so there are records where the combination of id and val are not unique).

Comment: @Beryllium all 3 of the queries I present should pick the latest value by timestamp. So it should handle it fine if your row were added to the sample table.

If there are 2 identical timestamps for the same value, that would cause a problem with the aggregate query.

Comment: +1 for "crutch"! Distinct is THE most widely used kludge to eliminate duplicates, when in fact there's a problem with the query. There are legitimate uses, but for me it's a red flag on the query whenever I see it.

Comment: Mysql has a neat workaround for this. Do you only want to see postgres answers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are grouping by `id` only

```
select
    id, max(ts)
  from x
  group by id 
  order by id
```

and if the group is composed of `id` and `val`

```
select
    id, val, max(ts)
  from
    x
  group by id, val
  order by id, val
```

so I would not use put the aggregate in a sub query (could be slower)
I would not use window agggregate functions either (because you can do it with plain `group by` and `max`)
and I would not use `distinct`, because this means something different (at least for me).

If you group on `id`, and you want *one* of the values of `val`, I suggest using the window aggregate functions, because you have to define somehow *which* `val` to choose: And this intention belongs into the `order by` right after `partition by`.

From a maintenance point of view I think that the window aggregate function really describes your intention - what you want to achieve. The other queries hide somehow their intent. Personally, when I read your queries, the 2nd one was the easiest one to understand.

From a performance point of view I can confirm that window aggregates are fast (at least in my cases). It could be that the optimizer benefits from the syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest and fastest:

```
select distinct on (id)
    id, ts, val
from t
order by id, ts desc
```

The `distinc on` (Postgresql only) will return only one row for each id. With the `order by` you control which one. In this case the last `ts`. With `distinct on` you can include in the result set as many columns as you need without the need for intermediary steps. The column(s) used in the `distinct on` must be included first in the `order by`.